# Casting to a type dynamically in VB

Tags: wpf, vb.net, user-interface, casting

I've been hunting through stackoverflow for a while to answer this.

I've got a Listview who's items are Listviews whose children are actually a list(of string) that is a member of the parent listviewitem.

Drag and drop functionality is the goal. However this is proving hard for a variety of reasons, one of which is casting. I need to get the type before I do a direct cast to make it work - at least I think that will get me over one problem.

However I can't get this syntax to even begin to work, so I'll start here:

```
   Dim itemType = listView.ItemContainerGenerator.ItemFromContainer(listViewItem)
   Dim g As Type = GetType(itemtype)
```

This is the entire drag n drop implementation I'm trying:

```
Dim startpoint As Point

Public Sub List_PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown(sender As Object, e As MouseEventArgs)
    ' Store the mouse position
    startpoint = e.GetPosition(Nothing)
End Sub

Private Sub List_MouseMove(sender As Object, e As MouseEventArgs)
    Dim mousePos As Point = e.GetPosition(Nothing)
    Dim diff As Vector = startpoint - mousePos
    If e.LeftButton = MouseButtonState.Pressed And Math.Abs(diff.X) > SystemParameters.MinimumHorizontalDragDistance Or Math.Abs(diff.Y) > SystemParameters.MinimumVerticalDragDistance Then
        Dim listView As ListView = DirectCast(sender, ListView)
        Dim listViewItem As ListViewItem = FindAncestor(Of ListViewItem)(DirectCast(e.OriginalSource, DependencyObject))
        Dim itemType = listView.ItemContainerGenerator.ItemFromContainer(listViewItem)
        Dim g As Type = GetType(itemtype)
        Dim item As String = DirectCast(listView.ItemContainerGenerator.ItemFromContainer(listViewItem), String)
        Dim dragData As New DataObject("myFormat", item)
        DragDrop.DoDragDrop(listViewItem, dragData, DragDropEffects.Move)
    End If

End Sub


Private Shared Function FindAncestor(Of T As DependencyObject)(current As DependencyObject) As T
    Do
        If TypeOf current Is T Then
            Return DirectCast(current, T)
        End If
        current = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(current)
    Loop While current IsNot Nothing
    Return Nothing
End Function

Private Sub DropList_DragEnter(sender As Object, e As DragEventArgs)
    If Not e.Data.GetDataPresent("myFormat") OrElse sender = e.Source Then
        e.Effects = DragDropEffects.None
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub DropList_Drop(sender As Object, e As DragEventArgs)
    If e.Data.GetDataPresent("myFormat") Then
        Dim contact As String = TryCast(e.Data.GetData("myFormat"), String)
        Dim listView As ListView = TryCast(sender, ListView)
        listView.Items.Add(contact)
    End If
End Sub
```

Here is the nested listView:

```
 <!--DataContext="{StaticResource RcpdInsertViewSource}" This is a collectionviewsource. 
                        RCPDInsert has a list(of string) member that is created from a single string property 
                        and whose order needs to be alterable. 
                        Eg rcpdInsert.template="[stuff] [more stuff]" so rcpdInsert.templateList = list(of String) from template.split("] [") -->
                        <ListView Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" ItemsSource="{Binding}"  
                                  PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown="List_PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown" 
                                  PreviewMouseMove="List_MouseMove"
                                  Drop="DropList_Drop" 
                                  DragEnter="DropList_DragEnter" 
                                  AllowDrop="True">

                                <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                                  <DataTemplate>
                                    <DockPanel>
                                        <TextBox Text="{Binding Path=cpID}"></TextBox>
                                        <TextBox Text="{Binding Path=fieldRef}"></TextBox>
                                        <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Path=InsertsList}" >
                                            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                                                <DataTemplate DataType="DataClasses1:RcpdInsert.template" >
                                                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Grid.Row="0">
                                                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding}" Margin="5" />
                                                    </StackPanel>
                                                </DataTemplate>
                                            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
                                        </ListView>
                                    </DockPanel>
                                </DataTemplate>
                            </ListView.ItemTemplate>

                        </ListView>
```

Goal: Drag and drop reordering of child listviews, ideally being able to pull individual items from one child listView to another. When saved, the code behind will actually concat the strings back together and update the template member.

For context here are the relevant members of RcpdInsert:

```
Sub SetupInsertList()
        _insertsList = template.Split(" ").ToList()
        For Each item In InsertsList
            Dim t = item
            RcpdList.Add(RcpdSet.RpcdListShared.Where(Function(x) x.insertID = t).ToList())
        Next
    End Sub

    Public Property RcpdList As New List(Of List(Of Rcpd))

    Private Property _insertsList As New List(Of String)

    Public Property InsertsList As List(Of String)
        Get
            If _insertsList.Count = 0 Then setupInsertList()
            Return _insertsList
        End Get
        Set(value As List(Of String))
            Dim combine As String = value.Aggregate("", Function(current, i) current + (i & " "))
            template = combine
        End Set
    End Property
```

The casting is one issue with this, I'm hoping being able to do this part means that the others will be easier to resolve.

Thanks in advance to anyone who can help :)

Comment: Have you used CType ?? instead of Gettype ??

Comment: CType(expression, typename)
. . .
typename : Any expression that is legal within an As clause in a Dim statement, that is, the name of any data type, object, structure, class, or interface.

Comment: @X-Factor ill try it when I get back home. Thank you. Haven't tried that syntax, though I thought ctype was for conversion not type discovery.

Comment: How about `itemType.GetType()` which gets the type of the object at runtime rather than compile time